# django error for attribute for charfield

Tags: python, django

this is my models.py file

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Album(models.Model):

    artist =  models.CharField(max_length=250)
    album_title = models.Charfield(max_length=500)
    genre = models.Charfield(max_length=100)
    album_logo = models.Charfield(max_length=1000)


class Song(models.Model):

    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.Cascade)
    file_type = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    song_title = models.Charfield(max_length=250)
```

i am getting errors for not found attribute of CharField

[error i am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nTy5.jpg)

Comment: No you aren't - you are getting errors because you have misspelled `CharField` as `Charfield` - Python is case-sensitive. In future questions, please paste the error traceback as text in the question rather than linking to a graphic.

Comment: If you get an IDE like Pycharm it will point out these errors for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you're getting errors for Charfield, not CharField. You've used that wrongly four times; Python is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Change your models.py,

Look for **Charfield**. It should be **models.CharField**.

That's what triggering the error. Python is strictly case-sensitive.

**Charfield** and **CharField** are both different.